# How can i change a line of code in the aspx.cs file after publishing the website

Tags: asp.net, web, publishing

I encountered with a problem, im not be able to fix it. The problem is i've to add a line of code in one of the code files(aspx.cs) of a published website.

Actually I developed a web application using ASP.NET & c# in vs 2008. I want deploy that website in another machine. I've only the published files with me. Now i've to add a line of code in one of the .cs files. In the deploying machine there is no vs 2008.

Please Please solve my problem. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, this is not a good practice to publish the code behinds.

Assuming that you have published the code behinds as well, changing the line of code in aspx.cs would not solve your problem as the application is using the dlls that have been created during the compile process.

So solution is to recompile your application with the change you have done, and copy the dlls across to the machine you want to deploy the app.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can change that code behind file using Adobe dreamweaver also. So if it is installed on your system then you can open .aspx page and then pressing ctrl + d on clickin code behind file .aspx.cs, i mean move your cursor to that file name and press ctrl + d.